# Does having old commented code and a lot of whitespaces in code slow down performance?

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, performance

Does having a lot of white space between chunks of code and empty lines in code slow down the performance of the application?

I have a tendency to space apart my code quite a bit, and I am wondering if it affects it negatively. Also, I have a lot of commented code that I commented out when I made changes, although I keep it around in case I ever have to go back to the old way. What are some other tips that could speed up performance?

Comment: It has no affect at all, it is compiled out.

Comment: Stop right there. You obviously have no idea of how compilers work, and while we're at it you may lack a clear concept of the low-level components (such as the CPU) too. That's no crime, but without this you lack the preconditions for reasoning about things like that, so please don't even try. Optimization is hard enough already.

Comment: Comments increase developer performance.

Comment: @Mathew, only if they are accurate... "Don't get suckered in by the comments -- they can be terribly misleading. Debug only code." --Dave Storer

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No performance degradation at all.  Comments are not parsed by the compiler, they are usually removed in the lexical analysis.

Comment: Feel free to add comments to your code for explaining your functions.  They also cause very negligible impact on your build process.

Comment: +1 ...and the compiled result is pure intermediate language codes (il), which is just the real execution stuff.

Answer (score 15):

Comments and whitespace have absolutely no effect.

Commented-**out** code should be removed however because it's "messy".

Keep your code in source control so you have version history, and never lose any historical changes.

Don't worry about optimization and speed until you notice your code being slow.  Then you profile code, measure, compare, time, etc to determine where bottlenecks are, and what the cause is.

Comment: Commented code should be removed?? I dont agree with that at all

Comment: -1 After spending over 30 years in software maintenance, I can say that comments do not make a program "messy".  The lack of comments for complex algorithms or when accessing hardware makes maintenance very difficult.  Also, look at http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual.html to see what can be done with comments.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews He's saying *commented-out code* is messy. Which I can confirm, and the sentiment is common at least here on SO. It's true that it says just "commented code" but from the context it's pretty obvious what's meant.

Comment: The poster didn't say comments make a program messy.  He said "commented code" makes it messy and I would have to agree.   Comments are absolutely necessary but big chunks of code that have been commented out do make things messy.

Comment: @mathematician1975: commented out code should not be commited to software repositories. You've got revision control for keeping previous versions.

Comment: @mathematician1975 It depends on the nature of the commented code in my option. If you do not have a specific reason in mind of why you would like to keep it around it is best to remove it. This is especially true if you have several programmers working on the code as it can lead to confusion.

Comment: OK I misunderstood what was meant here - I thought the suggestion was that **comments** should be removed as opposed to commented out **code**.

Comment: @delnan Theres a difference between commenting-*out* code and commented code. The industry term for removing code from compilation using comments is "commented-out".  The term for code with explanations is "commented code".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I already addressed that. I maintain that it is obvious that this answer talks about commented-out code (reasons: the question mentioning that; removing *the code* which which commented does not make sense; the next sentence talks about version history via source control which is precisely the reason commenting out code is not useful). You are being overly pedantic, and as much fun as that is, it doesn't help anyone here.

Comment: @delnan It was not obvious to me at all, however, this little block of comments will ensure that no other readers will make my mistake.

Comment: I meant commented-out code, however, most comments are unecessary as well.  Clean code doesn't need many.  Good variable and function names go a long way to eliminating the need for most of them.

Answer (score 7):

However its worth mentioning, in web envirnoment when you are NOT using a complied version of project then it matters, say you have 10,000 lines of comments/code in HTML/Css/Javascript then your browser will still download the chunk of data from webserver to your browser.

Answer (score 2):

Comments and whitespaces are not not compiled by any compiler and are ignored, so these two have no effect on performance. But in web technologies like HTML, CSS and JS, it can have effect on the file download because comments and whitespaces increases file size, and hence the webpage loading speed may degrade.

So it is best practice to keep your code as much clean as possible, and use a source control system like git to manage your code. Also, before the final production of your code, it is best practice to remove all unnecessary comments and whitespaces and old unused chunks of code.

Answer (score -1):

> No performance drops at all as its never compiled so no bit of that whitespace is compiled in to machine code and stufff

Comment: Could you include the link to the source of this quote?

Comment: You're repeating what has been said in three other answers. That's not necessary and basically, it adds noise.